# Cinema 4D Not Rendering

Tags: render, cinema-4d

I have added a project to the render queue, but after 15 minutes, nothing had rendered. I have no problems when rendering normally. This is Cinema 4D R15. How come it isn't rendering? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the render setting and option in it and make sure that you have chosen the destination folder. After setting this all, click the render button and wait for your video to process.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file close Cinema 4D and try rendering when you re-open it.

Make sure that you give it some time too if the project is big enough